# Error to Upload Image on server from iphone

Tags: php, ios, mysql, iphone

I am trying to upload photo on server using php. Actually I want to upload photo on server with save name in mysql database request with ASIFormDataRequest. I want upload photo on local server directory folder.

```
  if ([arrImages count] > 0) {
     NSString *strURL = @"http://localhost/ApneAreaMein/upload_file.php";

   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:@"This is sample text..." forKey:@"company_logo"];//Here write down the text which will be sent.

for (int i = 0; i < [arrImages count]; i++) {

    [request addData:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i] withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]];
}
[request startAsynchronous];
}
else {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please         select images..." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
 }
```

## My Php Code is

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root');
 mysql_select_db('apnemein_forms',$con);

 $uploaddir = 'http://localhost/apneareamein/uploads/'; //folder named upload, where       image will be saved (same dir as this file)
$file = basename($_FILES['company_logo']['company_logo']);

 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['company_logo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
 echo "File not uploaded"; //i'm not sure about this, but it works for me like this
 }
 else
 {
 echo "<img src=\"uploads/photopicker.jpg\" />";
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you path of uploading folder from

```
   $uploaddir = 'http://localhost/apneareamein/uploads/';
```

to
       $uploaddir = getcwd().'/uploads/';

This will solve your problem